# On restart server Ethernet went down saying not configured!

Tags: 11.10, networking, network-manager, ethernet

i justy have configured my dhcp server with static ip. after configuration dhcp server & routers were working fine. but after restarting server network connectivity went off. there are two lan cards but none of them is up.i tried setting up manually ip address again but it remains same. when i executed sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart i got this message

```
* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                          
/bin/sh: cannot open /etc/iptables_rules: No such file
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

i have configured my server according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112885/dhcp-server-not-routing-to-connect-to-internet-for-clients)

What is it the problem with ubuntu 11.10 or some configuration error. i am not getting it please help me.

Comment: As you were told in the linked question, you need to *create* the `/etc/iptables_rules` file by running `iptables-save > /etc/iptables_rules` *after* having set up your iptables correctly.

Comment: Also, this is a followup of a detail in your other AskUbuntu question, not a separate one.  Would you mind making them one single question?

Comment: it wont be a problem making them one single question, thanks

Comment: i tried this command "sudo killall NetworkManger" And it started working again. Thanks all for support.

Answer (score 1):

This question was solved by the OP:

> i tried this command `sudo killall NetworkManger` And it started working again